# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory

Tags: java, lucene

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Date;


import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;


public class OpenBookCrackIndexer {

    public static final Version luceneVersion = Version.LUCENE_43;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static int index(File indexDir, Directory dataDir) throws IOException {


        IndexWriterConfig luceneConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(
                luceneVersion, new StandardAnalyzer(luceneVersion));

        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dataDir, luceneConfig);

        File[] files = indexDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {

            if (file.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                Document document = new Document();

                String path = file.getCanonicalPath();

                document.getField(path);
                Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
                document.add(new TextField(path.toString(), reader));


                writer.addDocument(document);

            }
        }

        return writer.numDocs();
    }

    public static void search(String str) throws IOException, ParseException {
        if (str.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Error :"+str.toString());

        }

        File dataDir = new File("C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\print_imp\\Lucene");

        if (!dataDir.exists()) {
            throw new IOException(dataDir + "does not exist or is not a directory");
        }

//        String[] files = dataDir.list();
//        for(int i = 0;i< files.length;i++){
//          System.out.println(files[i].toString());
//        }

        Directory toSearch = new SimpleFSDirectory(dataDir);
        IndexReader indexreader = DirectoryReader.open(toSearch);

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexreader);

        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(luceneVersion);


        QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(luceneVersion, "Contents", analyzer);
        Query query = queryParser.parse(str);
        TopDocs td = searcher.search(query, 20);
        System.out.println("Number of hits: " + td.totalHits);

        for (int i = 0; i < td.totalHits; i++) {
            System.out.println("Doc Number " + td.scoreDocs[i].doc + "Score :" + td.scoreDocs[i].score);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        File indexDir = new File("C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\print_imp");
        File dataDir = new File("C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\print_imp\\Lucene");

        if (!indexDir.exists() || !dataDir.exists()) {
            throw new IOException(dataDir + "does not exist or is not a directory");
        }


        //SimpleFSDirectory SDindexDir = new SimpleFSDirectory(indexDir);
        SimpleFSDirectory SDdataDir = new SimpleFSDirectory(dataDir);

        //Directory dirIndex = SDindexDir;
        Directory dirData = SDdataDir;

        //long start = new Date().getTime();
        //int numIndexed = index(indexDir, dirData);
        //long end = new Date().getTime();

        //System.out.println("Indexed :" + numIndexed + " Time Took to Index: " + (end - start) + " milliseconds");

        search("Algorithms");

    }
}
```

here I am trying a basic File Directory indexing with lucene 4.3.. from book Lucene in Action. and due to Version Changes I could not use the code as it is ...
**Can any one Help me out with the error i am getting ...**

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory@C:\<PATH>lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@52fe85: files: [write.lock, _0.fdt, _0.fdx, _0.fnm, _0.nvd, _0.nvm, _0.si, _0_Lucene41_0.doc, _0_Lucene41_0.pos, _0_Lucene41_0.tim, _0_Lucene41_0.tip, _1.fdt, _1.fdx, _1.fnm, _1.nvd, _1.nvm, _1.si, _1_Lucene41_0.doc, _1_Lucene41_0.pos, _1_Lucene41_0.tim, _1_Lucene41_0.tip, _2.fdt, _2.fdx, _2.fnm, _2.nvd, _2.nvm, _2.si, _2_Lucene41_0.doc, _2_Lucene41_0.pos, _2_Lucene41_0.tim, _2_Lucene41_0.tip, _3.fdt, _3.fdx, _3.fnm, _3.nvd, _3.nvm, _3.si, _3_Lucene41_0.doc, _3_Lucene41_0.pos, _3_Lucene41_0.tim, _3_Lucene41_0.tip, _4.cfe, _4.cfs, _4.si, _5.cfe, _5.cfs, _5.si, _6.cfe, _6.cfs, _6.si, _7.cfe, _7.cfs, _7.si, _8.fdt, _8.fdx]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:741)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:52)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:66)
```

Comment: Have you checked whether there is a segments file?

Comment: @MarkLeightonFisher: I believe there is a directory listing embedded in the exception message, so you can check for yourself.

Comment: There is no segments file in the file list in the exception message. Like others have commented, looks like an unclosed Lucene writer or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [close](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#close%28%29) the `writer` in order to commit the changes!